# add to cart button should prompt log in screen

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

am doing sample shopping cart application , my requirement is when the ananymous user about to click on "add to cart" button then it should prompt for 'login.php' if it is success then only user can view the cart. Below is the add to cart button and iam using this sort of ajax call to check credentials. Please help thank you

```
echo "<input id=add type='button' onClick=\"window.open('cart.php?action=add&id=" . $id . "','_self');\" value='Add to Cart' />";  ====> "add to cart button"
```

## Ajax call

```
$("#login").click(function() {

            var action = $("#form1").attr('action');
            var form_data = {
            username: $("#username").val(),
            password: $("#password").val(),
            is_ajax: 1
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "login.php",
            data: form_data,
            success: function(response)
            {
                if(response == 'success')
                    $("#form1").slideUp('slow', function() {
                        $("#message").html("<p class='success'>You have logged in successfully!</p>");
                    });
                else
                    $("#message").html("<p class='error'>Invalid username and/or password.</p>");    
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
```

Comment: hi Please explain more details, Seriously am not get what you want to do..? and your id should be like this  id='add'. In single quotes.

Comment: Sir..when an anonymous user is about click the "add to cart" button then the login screen should appear to check the user is valid or not..so please check my "add to cart" button code

Comment: user1160126 One important things is that whenever a user click "ADD to CART " Button doesnt open a login window soon, Reason : If the user is alredy login should not redirect to login window. So when ever you click on add to cart button just call ajax for checking user is alredy loged in or not. ! if not open the login screen . ! Its just thought from my side. if u willing to explain more i try to help out. (..)

Comment: Yes sir..you are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as per SR's suggestions you should try something like this

remove this part from the button

```
onClick=\"window.open('cart.php?action=add&id=" . $id . "','_self');\
```

And here in the jquery code do these changes....or something synonymous, as per your requirements...

```
    $("#add").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()          // will stop the form from submitting...        
        var SKU_data = {sku : 12345, quantity:3} //some data related to the product to be sent to some script to add to cart

        var url_to_check_user_session = 'checkAuthentication.php' ;        //which can be the same as action
        $.get(url_to_check_user_session, {username: $("#username").val()}, function(data){
            if(data=='authenticated'){
                $.ajax({        //code to check the login authentication
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "addToCart.php",
                    data: SKU_data,
                    success: function(response)
                    {
                        if(response == 'success')
                            $("#message").html("<p class='error'>Product added to your cart.</p>");
                        else
                            $("#message").html("<p class='error'>Ohh!! something went wrong while adding the product to the cart.</p>");    
                    }
                });}
            else{               // now do the real thing
                $("#form1").slideDown();
                $("#login").click(function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "login.php",
                        data: form_data,
                        success: function(response)
                        {
                            if(response == 'success')
                                $("#form1").slideUp('slow', function() {
                                    $("#message").html("<p class='success'>You have logged in successfully!</p>");
                                });
                            else
                                $("#message").html("<p class='error'>Invalid username and/or password.</p>");    
                        }
                    });
                })
                }
            })

        return false;
    });
```

hope this helps...

Comment: This stackoverflow make people lazzy. what google is doing now..! for every simple thing people serch it in google. Stackoverflow doing it more than that. Anyhow Its fine.